# RGB Extractions from MediaProjection Screen Captures?

Tags: java, android, screenshot, surfaceview, android-mediaprojection

How can I extract rgb values from surfaceviews containing mediaprojection screen captures? I have [MediaProjectionDemo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/bf1e262/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/projection/MediaProjectionDemo.java) working and would prefer to use something like [RenderScript](http://werner-dittmann.blogspot.com/2016/03/using-android-renderscript-to-convert.html) for speed.

Comment: Are you aware of this graphical demos project/repo: https://github.com/google/grafika (more as a starting place for research not a final solution)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks, I have now d/l and run that. I am checking it for info.